# Force dark mode in pyqt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

I have a browser that is working, but when I try to use flags to force Google to open in dark mode, it doesn't work.

This is what it opens to:

[image]

These are the flags I have tried:

```py
os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = "--force-dark-mode"
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

```py
os.environ["QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS"] = --blink-settings=darkMode=4,darkModeImagePolicy=2"
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

As well as a couple other flags I tried I can't find.

Any solutions?